# Typescript: Overloading generic methods

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

How is the best wat to translate these Java method signatures to typescript:

```
public <E> Expression<E> setProjection(Expression<E> e) {
   //return ...
}

public Expression<?> setProjection(Expression<?>... o) {
    for (Expression<?> e : o)
        this.setProjection(Projections.tuple(o));
    return //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In TypeScript you can satisfy both with a single method signature (if I'm interpreting things right)...

```
public setProjection<E>(...e: Expression<E>[]): Expression<E> {
```

You can call this with one expression, or many expressions. You can test the length of `e` if you want to know whether you were passed one, or more than one.

If you don't care about `E`, you can make it dynamic, using `setProjection<any>`.

Additional note: overloads in TypeScript all decorate a single method... this leads you to a single implementation... which leads you to not overloading as the signature works each way. The overload would have looked like:

```
public setProjection<E>(e: Expression<E>): Expression<E>;
public setProjection<E>(...e: Expression<E>[]): Expression<E>;
public setProjection<E>(...e: Expression<E>[]): Expression<E> {
```

But it would be identical to the non-overloaded version.

I haven't covered the implementation details of the method as the question is on the overloading aspect.